# SQL Server IF..ELSE do not show at Windows Application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, if-statement, table-variable

I have this stored procedure:

```
exec sp_Defect_B '2013-05-20 00:00:00','2013-05-25 23:59:59'
```

Which has a `IF..ELSE` to execute different thing depends on the code given:

```
alter proc [dbo].[p_Defect_B] (@dtFrom datetime, @dtTo datetime)            
as            
begin  
DECLARE @Total TABLE 
(
  [No] int, TSampel float
)
-- Total
insert into @Total
select 1 as [No], SUM(H.Total) as TSampel from TrxDBHHDr HH
left join TrxDBHdr H on HH.DBNO=H.DBNO
left join ProductType PT on H.ACd=PT.ACd and PT.GCd=1
where HH.Deleted=0 and HH.DBDate between @dtFrom and @dtTo

DECLARE @Defect TABLE 
(
  DefectCd varchar(15),Name varchar(50), Defect float
)
-- Defect
insert into @Defect
select D.DefectCd,DB.Name,sum(coalesce(D.Qty,0)) as Defect from TrxDBHHDr HH
left join TrxDBDtl D on HH.DBNO=D.DBNO
left join ProductType PT on D.acd=PT.ACd and PT.GCd=1
left join DefectBK DB on DB.DefectCd=D.DefectCd
where HH.Deleted=0 and HH.DBDate between @dtFrom and @dtTo
group by D.DefectCd,DB.Name

DECLARE @SubTotal TABLE 
(
  Name varchar(50), Defect float, TSampel float, PDefect float
)
insert into @SubTotal
select D.Name,D.Defect,T.TSampel,D.Defect*100/T.TSampel as PDefect from @Defect D
left join @Total T on T.[No]=1
order by PDefect desc

DECLARE @TotalD TABLE 
(
  [No] int,Defect float
)

insert into @TotalD
select 1, Sum(D.Defect) as Defect from @Defect D

insert into @SubTotal
select 'Total Defect', D.Defect, T.TSampel, D.Defect*100/T.TSampel as PDefect from @TotalD D
left join @Total T on T.[No]=1

select * from @SubTotal
end
```

I execute the code in SSMS and it worked perfectly. But when I try to use the code in C# Windows application it doesn't get any value.... How is that possible? Did I miss anything?

Only this stored procedure didn't return table value....

I tried using temp table, table variable, they still didn't return table value...

This is the C# Code:

```
sql= "exec p_Defect_B '2013-05-20 00:00:00','2013-05-25 23:59:59'";

RunQuery qu_data = new RunQuery();
DataTable data = new DataTable();
data = qu_data.OpenAdoQuery(sql,"IP")
```

This is part of my program of my connection C# to SQL Server

```
myCon = new OleDbConnection(strCon);
DataTable myData = new DataTable();

myCon.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter myOleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
myOleAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql,myCon);
myOleAdapter.Fill(myData);
myCon.Close();
```

- All the tables return value in SMSS.
- All table variable show result    in SMSS.
- The result didn't show on C# Windows Application using ADOAdapter.
- I tried using Temp Table and Table Variable, didn't work.
- I tried not using `IF..ELSE`, didn't work.

Comment: You should avoid using the `sp_` prefix - it's reserved for SQL Server's System procedures.

Comment: I changed the sp_Defect_B to p_Defect_B and still didn't catch the table value from the procedure.

Comment: surely there's a better set based approach?

Comment: Well, the other issue is that your dumping a **ton** of code at us, when we don't have your database - we have no way to debug your issue. You need to do some debugging yourself and narrow the issue down.

Comment: Can u tell my some other ways to get this kind of approach? I want to get the set of search with many variable that give different type of result. What I have try to narrow: 1. Only this store procedure do not return table values, 2. I used temp table and temp variable in other stored procedure, it worked fine. 3. This is the first time using IF..ELSE statement. 4. This is also first time that create result that have different column name. (1 stored procedure create 3 type of columns result). 5. It worked fine in SMSS, but do not work on C# Windows application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use the `SqlConnection` then connecting to SQL Server - and you should execute your stored procedure using a standard `SqlCommand` - don't use the `EXEC....` code.

Try this code:

```
// setup connection and command
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here-))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.p_Defect_B", conn))
{
    // define command as stored procedure
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // define and set parameter values
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime(2013, 5, 20);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = new DateTime(2013, 5, 25, 23, 59, 59);

    // execute your query
    conn.Open();

    // get a data reader to read the values from the result set
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // iterate over the result set
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            // fetch the values - depends on your result set - YOU NEED TO ADAPT THIS!
            var value1 = rdr.GetInt(0);
            var value2 = rdr.GetString(1);
            ......
        }

        rdr.Close();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```